# C++ Linker Errors: The Linker Keeps Trying to Include Files that Used to Exist and Fails

Tags: c++, linker

I'm working on a game engine in C++ Visual Studio 2010. I've been writing C++ for a little while now but I never learned how linkers work or how to debug Linker related errors. Google hasn't been much help.

I'm currently getting an error as follows:
c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: Old_Path\File_Name.cpp'

I get this error on about 4 files that used to be in a different directory. I changed the directory to be make my project structure more clear. The old directory no longer exists at all. I have been thorough in changing every corresponding include (checked every file multiple times. The includes themselves give me no errors). However, the path specified by the error is the old path, not the new path.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: That's not a linker error, that's a compiler error.

Comment: Is it? I'm not getting any line number or anything else that would help me diagnose any problems in the source code.

Comment: The linker works on *object* files, which are the result of compiling *source* files.

Comment: I would do something like `find project_dir -type f | xargs grep File_Name.cpp` to find out where it's used.

Answer (score 1):

Remove(not delete) Those four files from your project then add them form menu - Project - Add existing item and Rebuild you project. 
by the way if you haven't define any search path for your source files, cpp files must be in directory if corresponding header files.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if your global build settings are **not** set to automatically save files before building the project. The build steps use an external process and the current version of the project file saved on disk to build the project. Because of this you need to manually save the project file after removing (and sometimes adding) files before the build will be successful. You can go to the "File" menu and select "Save All", hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> to save all files or reopen the project.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like your `vcxproj` file is corrupted. This file, among other things, maintains a list of all the header and code files that are part of your Visual Studio project. If that list of files gets out of sync with the actual files present in your project's directory, the compiler will be instructed to use files that do not exist.

Any mismatches *should* be marked with an error icon on the file in your project hierarchy displayed in the Solution Explorer. From there, you can right-click on the item and either "Include In Project" or "Exclude From Project".

If that doesn't work, you can also try closing the project in Visual Studio and opening the vcxproj file in a text editor to fix it manually. For example, near the bottom of a project file I have open now, I see:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="BoundedInteger.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="stdafx.h" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="stdafx.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="BoundedInteger.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="Test.cpp" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Make sure that the information stored there actually matches the files you want to be part of the project, and the files that you actually have on disk. Once you've done that, re-open the project in VS and "Rebuild All".

Answer (score -3):

> How can I fix this error?

By starting a new project.

Comment: I've actually tried that. I'm working off of a project I picked up elsewhere though and I can never seem to get all the libraries and stuff working on my own when I start from scratch (Again, stuff at the Linker level is pretty much foreign to me.)